# Integer Computation Script

Tags: sh

Yesterday I posted a question in another thread about a project I'm working on. I'm very new to UNIX programming, and I'm having quite a few struggles with my script. Let me start off by stating the script purpose.

Purpose: Using a separate function for each computation, the script will compute and print if each integer is even or odd, prime (or not), and the integer factors of arguments entered on the command line. This function shall be called for each numeric command line argument. If a non-integer is entered the script will produce an error message and move on to the next number. I MUST use the Bourne shell.

Question - After making some good progress I'm stumped on two fronts:
***1: If I enter 1 as one of my arguments the output repeats twice that "1 is not a prime number." 
2: I've tried using the dev/null command, but haven't been able to find the correct code to trigger an error if a non-integer argument is entered.***
Any help with either of these is appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
prime () {
if [ $Num -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo "$Num is not a prime number"
fi

Pcheck=`factor $Num|wc -w`
if [ $Pcheck -eq 2 ]
then
echo "$Num is a prime number"
else
echo "$Num is not a prime number"
fi
}

even_odd () {
rem=$(( $Num % 2))
if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$Num is an even number"
else
    echo "$Num is an odd number"
fi
}

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
Num=$1
prime Num
even_odd Num
shift
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to complete the script save the error message if a non-numerical value is input.

```
#!/bin/sh

factors () {
i=1
while [ $i -le $Num ]
do
if [ `expr "$Num" % $i` -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -n "$i "
fi
i=`expr $i + 1`
done | sort -nu
}
prime () {
Pcheck=`factor $Num|wc -w`
if [ $Pcheck -eq 2 ]
then
echo "$Num is a prime number"
else
echo "$Num is not a prime number"
fi
}
even_odd () {
rem=$(( $Num % 2))
if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$Num is an even number"
else
    echo "$Num is an odd number"
fi
}
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
Num=$1
if [ "$Num" -eq "$Num" ] 2>/dev/null
then
echo “$Num is not a valid number “
fi
prime Num
even_odd Num
factors Num
shift
done
```